# Верстка шаблон, как сделать такой слайдер

Tags: адаптивная-верстка, bootstrap4

[image: Как сделать такой слайдер?]

Скорее всего сам я его не сделаю, т.к. знаю только html, css, сейчас учусь верстать с помощью bootstrap4.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Comment: Учите заодно JavaScript. тут без него никак.

Comment: Добавьте ваши попытки в вопрос, ваш [mcve], что именно не получилось? в чем возникли сложности? И вам подскажут